# Germany colonizing Europe?

Tags: hitler

Was Hitler stopped because the countries he began colonizing(called - annexing/invading by historians) were Christian and European?

Well:

When European countries invaded, plundered and murdered non European countries such Abysinnia, and non Christian countries and peoples, no other European nation/power bothered. Was Hitler stopped because he was doing the same thing to European Christian countries?

Comment: I'm sorry - I don't understand your question. If you are asking whether Hitler would have been victorious over non-Europeans, that is a counterfactual, and we don't discuss those here - see [ask]

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace: I think that the question is, was Hitler opposed because his victims were Poland and France, rather than say, "Abysinnia?"

Comment: I vote to reopen. This is a perfectly valid question, under the interpretation suggested by @TomAu.

Comment: There is a tremendous difference between conquest & colonization; the question compares apples and oranges.

Comment: The question hasn't backed up its premise (that "no other European nation/power bothered"). Leopold's Rape of Congo provoked massive international outrage that ended the Congo Free State, for example. And Anglo-French plans to capitulate to Italian ambitions over Abyssinia likewise resulted in mass outrage. Clearly *some people* were bothered. Plus it's not really sensible to compare expansionism close to your borders with expansionism a continent away.

Comment: @Semaphore Seems to me, you are beginning to give a good answer here.... :)

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace The German policy in the East certainly included a very strong element of colinization.

Comment: Hitler was stopped because western countries were afraid that Germany would growth stronger than them. British would otherwise not care what happens to jews or polish. Soviet Union killed 5 million Ukrainians and no one bothered to stop them. For humanitarian reasons USA could sent few bombers over Serbia, but they would not invade china or russia.